# How to assure correct order of promises in promise all using redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I am using redux (and react) and I have to make multiple api requests a certain number of times. I am using a for loop and promise all. The order promises are being resolved is the problem as the order is random - first the 2nd promise gets resolved, then first, then 3rd instead of 1,2,3.
Am I doing something wrong or how can I change the order ? Also, what would be the way to stop the iteration when I am not receiving any data? I would have to iterate about 25 times, but dont want to hard code it. Could I use my catch to determine that? Thanks a lot!

Action:

```
export const fetchData = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        const promises = [];

        dispatch({type: FETCHING_DATA})

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            const start = i === 0 ? 0 : (i + "01");
            let getData = axios.get(`${api_root_url}/v1/?start=${start}`)    
                .then(res => {
                    dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, payload: res.data})
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_ERR, payload: err.data})
                })
            promises.push(getData)
        }
        return Promise.all(promises)    
    }
}
```

Comment: If the order is important, don't use `Promise.all`,..  Instead chain your promises,.  If you can use `async / await`, this is really simple.

Comment: You cannot use `Promise.all()` *and* a fixed order.

Comment: Another option, if you can wait until all promises have finished, you could then dispatch after your `Promise.all`..  The returned order of `Promise.all` is consistent, just not the order the promises are executed.

Comment: Use async/await if you can, otherwise instead of `Promise.all()`, you can use bluebird's `Promise.each()` to ensure each promise executes in order based on the order it's in the array of promises: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

Comment: Is this an action that is initiated by user action? Problem with that is that user can initiate action ABC and then the promises of those actions resolve in order ACB, so the last action of the user was C but UI shows result of B. This problem and it's solution is demonstrated in [this pen](https://codepen.io/amsterdamharu/pen/KRQKLj) click 5 and within 5 seconds click 1 press F12 and see the order of clicks and order of resolved asynchronous code that was initiated by those actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try 2 things if the order of the actions dispatched when resolving the 3 requests is important:

Just dispatch the actions after all 3 are finished:

```
export const fetchData = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        const promises = [];

        dispatch({type: FETCHING_DATA});
        Promise.all(
          [...new Array(3)].map((ignore,i)=>i === 0 ? 0 : (i + "01"))
          .map(
            start=>axios.get(`${api_root_url}/v1/?start=${start}`)
          )  
        ).then(
          results=>results.forEach(
            result=>
              dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, payload: result.data})
            )
        ).catch(
          err => dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_ERR, payload: err.data})
        );
        //not sure why you want to return something here
        //return Promise.all(promises)    
    }
}
```

Or keep your code as is but in `dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, payload: result.data})` add what request has finished so the reducer knows where to update the state. Something like `dispatch({type: FETCH_DATA_SUCESS, payload: {request_from:start,data:res.data}})` and the same for the catch statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used your code and I am getting now the results in order. Could you please explain, why dispatching the acting for all resolved promises leads to an ordered list and why it doesnt when I dispatch the action before like I did so I understand better? Thank you!!

Comment: @javascript2016 Say that `one`,`two` and `three` are promises resolving in reverse order. then for `Promise.all([one,two,three]).then(results=>...` the results (resolve values of the promises) would be in the order as passed to Promise.all. But if you do `[one,two.three].forEach(p=>p.then(console.log(resolve))` it would log three, two, one as the console.log immediately logs the resolve when a promise resolves. Promise.all([array of promises]) will resolve when all promises in the array are resolved passing to then the resolve values the order the array was passed.

Comment: @javascript2016 It's all in the location of the `.then`

Comment: Okay , I see. Thanks for explaining! Just one side question: So far Im hard coding the point until when it should iterate because I know how muh data Im receiving, which is bad because the amount of data could change. Is there a way I could iterate up to the point, where Im not receiving data / the catch would get triggered?

Comment: @javascript2016 That depends on your api,maybe it returns empty and maybe it returns an error but succesfull response with error in json, could be anything. as commented in your other question: These seem to be problems you are fixing at the wrong end. I guess you are using an API that you have no control over.

Comment: Yes, I cant really change anything about that api